# rails how to merge user id in nested attributes while updating with parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, update-attributes

I'm using rails 3.0.9

I've models with `has_many :through` association, where user can create new child records while creating the new parent record and while updating the parent record, user can create/delete child records

For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments_posts
  has_many :comments, :through => :comments_posts
  attr_accessible :title, :post_text, :comments_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
  validates :user_id, :title, :post_text, :presence => true
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_text
  has_many :comments_posts
  has_many :posts, :through => :comments_posts
  validates :comment_text, :user_id, :presence => true
end

class CommentsPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In posts_controller.rb i'm also saving/updating the comments records using `fields_for` to form nested_attributes in Post's `form_for` and the parameter formed as expected.

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
end
```

**Problem is:**

Here i can't merge the `user_id` column for every new nested comments attributes in the `params[:post][:comments_attributes]` which will be ignored by `attr_accessible`.

Is there any best way to merge/assign the `user_id` column to each comment records?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but aren't you missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments` in your `Post` model? If that doesn't fix it, can you post the error message you're seeing?

Comment: @Geoff that right i'm using it but i missed to post, but actually problem is i want to merge value for `user_id` column in update action which is not passed through the parameter, without merging the value for `user_id` i got user id can't be blank error message

Comment: The associations here are very confusing. Why do you have the CommentsPost model? Can one comment belong to several posts? That doesn't seem to make any sense. The more logical (and common) approach would be to have the Comment model belong_to a Post which in turn has_many Comments (no through)

Comment: @DanneManne I just explained for a example for my scenario (never mind on model names)

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry for questioning it. I'd say that you can either create a custom update method in the Post model that will do the merging of attributes before passing it on to update_attributes. Or else you might be able to fetch the user_id in a before_save callback from the Comment model. But then you have to bypass the validation of user_id, otherwise the before_save will never be called.